# How to remove -fPIE compiler switch from Qt Creator

Tags: qt

I am using Qt Creator 3.0.1, GCC 4.8.1, Qt 5.2.1 on Opensuse 13.1
my problem is I can not remove -fPIE switch by adding QMAKE_CXXFLAGS -= fPIE to the .pro file
How can I remove it ?

Comment: Are you sure that it is needed cause your program later will not link to Qt as it is compiled with that option?

Comment: in this project I am not using Qt, It is a console app but I want to use qt creator

Comment: Even in non-qt code, this is a bad idea. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_APP which contains -fPIE switch for gcc, Ive just set it to nothing(QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_APP =) and I dont see -fPIE switch in make output anymore

Comment: thank you for your answer nib, but it did not worked for me, qt editor did not even realized QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_APP as keyword

Comment: QtCreator will not highlight/autocomplete that variable. Do you have `CONFIG -= qt` in project file? Btw Ive posted my example project file http://paste.kde.org/p39eqqntl/rusbpo/raw . And do not forget to run qmake recursively for all targets / clean all:)