# How to build QT with -reduce-relocations

Tags: c++, qt

I am using Ubuntu 16.04, cmake 3.10.1, QT 5.6.2.
I used to develop applications on windows, so I am not sure how to trouble shoot on linux platform.

When I compile my code, I get error

```
In file included from /usr/local/Qt/5.6.2/5.6/gcc_64/include/QtCore/qcoreapplication.h:37:0,
                 from /usr/local/Qt/5.6.2/5.6/gcc_64/include/QtWidgets/qapplication.h:37,
                 from /usr/local/Qt/5.6.2/5.6/gcc_64/include/QtWidgets/QApplication:1,
                 from /home/sulfred/Documents/SoftwareDev/github/SulfredLee/PcapReplayer/BackEnd/main.cpp:3:
/usr/local/Qt/5.6.2/5.6/gcc_64/include/QtCore/qglobal.h:1087:4: error: #error "You must build your code with position independent code if Qt was built with -reduce-relocations. " "Compile your code with -fPIC (-fPIE is not enough)."
 #  error "You must build your code with position independent code if Qt was built with -reduce-relocations. "\
    ^
```

Q1.
How to verify that my Qt was built with `-reduce-relocations`.

Comment: Did you see this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24825093/how-to-remove-fpie-compiler-switch-from-qt-creator

Comment: Thank you very much, but I am not using QMake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously Qt is already compiled with `-reduce-relocations`; the error message points out that you must build your own code using the appropriate flags. Related:

[Error while compiling QT project in cmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15978608/error-while-compiling-qt-project-in-cmake)

https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/qtbase/commit/36d6eb721e7d5997ade75e289d4088dc48678d0d

So just try to add either the `-fPIE` or `-fPIC` flag to your compiler flags.

Comment: Thank you very much. Here is what I am using in my `CMakeLists.txt`, `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-Wall -fPIC -std=c++11")`.

Answer (score 3):

In modern CMake, add the `-fPIC` compile flag using [`target_compile_options()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_options.html):

```
add_executable(MyExecutable ...)
target_compile_options(MyExecutable PRIVATE -fPIC)
```

Also, Qt is often unsatisfied with `fPIE`, but it needs `-fPIC`. Using the CMake variable [`CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE.html) to set `fPIC` only works for **library** targets. This variable will add `fPIE` to **executable** targets, which is not sufficient for Qt. So use `target_compile_options()` to set `fPIC` explicitly instead.

Answer (score 0):

> I am using Ubuntu 16.04, **cmake** 3.10.1, QT 5.6.2.

Do not forget to link to the Qt component you're using. `-fPIC` will be added automatically in this case:

```
find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Widgets REQUIRED)
add_executable(foo main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(foo PRIVATE Qt5::Widgets)
```